# Eclipse CDT does not recognize executables with file extensions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

As the title says, my Eclipse CDT does not recognize executables with file extensions. However, the problem is not that I have specified a wrong binary parser. I use the Elf parser and it recognizes all my executables correctly, as long as they don't have a file extension. If I change my executables with extensions from e.g. `foo.dbg` to `foo`, then they are also recognized correctly.

I would like to continue structuring my executables with extensions, so is there anything I can do? Any option in the settings I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your preferences:

General -> Editors -> File Associations

Maybe the .dbg is already associated with an editor.

**Edit:** With CDT, you should probably add the .gdb extension in the list of executable file types. To do so, go to Preferences, in General -> Content Type, open Binary File, click on Executable File, then on the Add button. Then enter *.gdb in the dialog box.